# Что такое рекурсия?

Tags: рекурсия

Обьясните, пожалуйста, что такое рекурсия? От простого к сложному, на примерах.

Comment: http://www.netlore.ru/upload/files/19/large_1_224.jpg

Comment: а подробнее,от простого к сложному

Comment: Баян, но всё же:

> Чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно понять
> рекурсию.

Comment: Можете [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/120510/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F) ознакомиться что такое рекурсия.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov  ссылка рулит :)

Comment: ![:D][1]


  [1]: http://cs317725.userapi.com/v317725389/1574/b0_2OFJQI2k.jpg

Comment: Подробное объяснение рекурсии: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444675/181472

Answer (score 5):

Это когда функция вызывает саму себя в себе самой. Довольно лёгкое понятие, и частенько используется. Хорошо что спросили - это надо знать.

```
function Test(x, y) {
    ... действия
    ... тут
    Test(3, 4)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

На примерах. Язык не важен, главное вникнуть.

Допустим нам нужно вычислим факториал первых 10 чисел

берем в итерационном(цикл) варианте

```
factorial := 1;

    for i:=10 to n do
        factorial := factorial * i;
```

Ну это простой пример. Тоже самое можно сделать и рекурсией, единственное нужно помнить про выход из неё, чтобы не было зацикливания.

```
Function factorial(N: integer) : longint; 
Begin 
   If N= 0 then 
   Factorial := 1 
   Else Factorial := factorial(N-1) * N 
End;
```

вызываем так

```
 вывод на экран factorial(10); // вернет факториал первых 10 чисел
```

если не наврал, то так выглядит рекурсия :)

Comment: >factorial(N-1) * N   //  а это по твоему что?

Comment: На самом деле рекурсия факториала, это самое простое, что можно написать. Повторюсь, тут главное понять как оно все работает и зачем нужно. Не всегда нужна рекурсия, и так же иногда она просто спасает.

Comment: написать сложное не составит труда ,если понимаешь,как оно работает

Answer (score 4):

**Простое**: функция вызывает саму себя.

**Сложное**: функция A вызывает ф-ю B, та вызывает ф-ю C, которая, в свою очередь, вызывает ф-ю A. Круг замкнулся. Ура, рекурсия!

В графике красивые штуки получаются когда используется самоподобие. Напр. на Processing'е [примеры](http://processing.org/learning/topics/penrosesnowflake.html). А среда для программного рисования под названием [ContextFree](http://www.contextfreeart.org/) и вовсе целиком построена на рисовании самоподобных структур.

Answer (score 3):

Примеры рекурсии:

1. факториал. `(n+1)!=(n+1)*n!` Прерывание рекурсии при n=0.
2. логарифм. `ln(x)=(x-1)/x+...+(x-1)^n/nx^n`. Следующий член ряда вычисляется рекурсивно через рекурентную формулу `A(n+1)=A(n)*(x-1)*n/((n+1)*x)` Прерывание рекурсии осуществляется когда вычисленный член ряда меньше некой заранее заданной дельты.
3. обход дерева. для каждого узла дерева вызываем обход каждого дочернего узла дерева.
4. сортировка. для сортировки массива делим массив на большие и меньшие значения относительно опорного, сортируем большие, затем меньшие.
5. ...

Comment: Я предполагаю, что ТС имел ввиду под "на примерах" это значи на примерах, а не предоставить примеры рекурсий, а написать пример для разбора этой самой рекурсии.

Comment: Надо добавить, что обязательно должно быть ограничение рекурсии, иначе переполнится стек возврата.

Comment: @Shrek это примеры рекурсии в качестве примеров рекурсии от простого к сложному. Описать рекурсию без примеров, это как описать вкус клубники формулами аминокислот.

Comment: @sercxjo Ну тут не всё так однозначно. Хвостовая рекурсия/хвостовые вызовы современными компиляторами хорошо оптимизируются.

А по существу вопроса. Многие алгоритмы изначально имеют рекурсивный характер (тот же факториал). Их можно привести к нерекурсивной, итеративной форме, но они становятся менее понятными и более громоздкими.

И инструмент, позволяющий справиться с рекурсией и итерацией один (по Э. Дейкстре) -- математическая индукция

Comment: @alexlz и частенько более быстрыми)

Comment: @rasmisha Сильно зависит от. Если алгоритм достаточно сложный, то его преобразование при недостатке опыта и/или времени может быть настолько неудачным, так что никакой компилятор потом несоптимизирует.

Да, если можно, то хотелось бы увидеть пример.

Comment: @alexlz, а все таки итеративное вычисление факториала *и проще и быстрее* рекурсивного. Посмотрите пример @Shrek.

Пример рекурсии с факториалом прост (а главное короток), но он дурацкий (по сравнению с очевидной итерацией) и поэтому вызывает негативное отношение к методу вообще. К сожалению короткий, содержательный и эффектно показывающий достоинства рекурсии пример в голову не приходит. 

Поиск в двоичном дереве в глубину все таки длинноват и для законченности требует еще и функцию построения дерева.

Comment: Банальный обход многомерного массива, по моему, весьма неплохо демонстрирует рекурсию:

    def print_list(arr, ident=1):
        for val in arr:
           if isinstance(val, list): print_list(val, ident + 1)
           else: print("==" * ident, val)

    print_list(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['e', ['f'], 'g']], 'h'])
    # == a
    # == b
    # ==== c
    # ==== d
    # ====== e
    # ======== f
    # ====== g
    # == h

Comment: мне почему-то тоже сразу пришёл в голову Flatten

Comment: @avp

    int fact (int n, int acc) {
        if (n == 1) return acc;
        else return fact (n-1, acc * n);
    }


    fact:
    .LFB34:
       .cfi_startproc
       movl 4(%esp), %edx
       movl 8(%esp), %eax
       cmpl $1, %edx
       je .L2
       .p2align 4,,7
       .p2align 3
    .L4:
        imull %edx, %eax
        subl $1, %edx
        cmpl $1, %edx
        jne .L4
     .L2:
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

А насчёт факториалов The Evolution of a Haskell Programmer http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

Comment: вычисление факториала с помощью хвостовой рекурсии - редкость

Comment: @alexlz, в комментарии я, естественно, имел в виду **исходный** код на ЯВУ. Пример в ответе @Shrek.

Comment: @avp Просто тут вопрос, что легче -- трансформировать рекурсию в хвостовую рекурсию или в итерации. Для большинства программистов, имеющих опыт сугубо императивного программирования, второе -- нормально и естественно, а первое -- выглядит странным фокусом.

Хотя изначально должно бы быть наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Что такое рекурсия ?

См. рекурсия.

Comment: бесконечный луп, практическая польза - только тепло от процессора )