# Как работает рекурсивная функция?

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Как работате эта функция?

```
//Программа вычисляет факториал числа.
//Число передается в строку "//1"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fact(int n);
int main()
{
    cout<<"factorial="<<fact(4);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int fact(int n)
{
    int ans;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    ans=fact(n-1)*n;
    return (ans);
}
```

Comment: Здесь 2 функции. main - основная функция приложения, fact - функция вычисления факториала. Факториал вычисляется циклическим вызовом функции fact. В первый раз fact вызывается из main, затем пока аргумент функции не станет 1, она вызывает сама себя с уменьшением аргумента на 1. В кратце как-то так. Кстати алгоритм не имеет проверок аргументов и не сможет обработать аргументы меньше 1.

Comment: окей,а если передать fact(2),то получится что функция не будет рабоать?т.к n-1=1

Comment: @user186578: почему же не будет? будет.

Comment: На будущее: когда задаете вопрос, объясняйте подробнее, что вам уже понятно, а что — ещё нет, что вы ожидали получить и что получили вместо этого. Рекомендую прочитать: [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Факториал натурального числа N — это произведение всех чисел от 1 до N включительно.

Факториал 1 равен 1. Во всех остальных случаях факториал (N) равен факториалу (N-1) * N.

```
int ans;
if(n==1) return 1;
```

В этом примере `fact(int n)` — это рекурсивная функция, она вызывает сама себя.

Например, программа считает факториал числа 4.

```
fact(4) =
fact(3) * 4 = 
(fact(2) * 3) * 4 = 
((fact(1) * 2) * 3) * 4 = 
((1) * 2 ) * 3 ) * 4 =
1 * 2 * 3 * 4;
```

Как это работает по рекурсивным вызовам:

```
fact(4) доходит до строки ans=fact(n-1)*n; и запрашивает результат fact(3).
  fact(3) аналогично запрашивает результат fact(2)
    fact(2) запрашивает результат fact(1)
      fact(1): выполняется условие if(n==1) return 1; и возвращается 1.
    полученный результат умножается на 2, возвращается 2
  полученный результат умножается на 3, возвращается 6
полученный результат умножается на 4, возвращается 24
```

Подробнее о рекурсии можно прочитать:

- [в описании метки [рекурсия]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F/info)
- [Что такое рекурсия?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/120510/181472)

Comment: Спасибо тебе, мил человек. Ты спас мой мозг от взрыва. В несколько строчек объяснил то, что многие не могут за получасовое видео объяснить и в многостраничной статье растолковать.

Comment: @AndreyKarpov рад, что вам пригодилось.

Answer (score 6):

Может быть станет понятней, если переписать ее совсем коротко

```
int fact (int n) {
  return n > 1 ? fact(n - 1) * n : 1;
}
```

fact() циклически вызывает саму себя, каждый раз с аргументом на 1 меньше, чем ее вызвали до тех пор, пока ее не вызовут с аргументом, равным 1. В этом случае она вернет 1. В остальных случаях она возвращает произведение n на результат, который возвращает fact(n - 1).

Все это  почти дословно соответствует [определению факториала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB).

Эквивалентная реализация

```
int fact (int n) {
  int r[n + 1], i;

  r[0] = r[1] = 1;
  for (i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) 
    r[i] = r[i - 1] * i;

  return r[n];
}
```

А в случае рекурсивной функции массив `r[]` неявно организуется в виде стека активаций функции fact.

Поскольку для вычисления `fact(n)` достаточно знать значение `fact(n - 1)`, то очевидно эффективным алгоритмом будет простая итерация, где на каждом шаге цикла мы будем умножать уже вычисленный факториал на счетчик шагов цикла. Заодно проверим допустимость входного параметра (факториал определен для целых неотрицательных чисел) и переполнение (т.е. вмещается ли очередной промежуточный результат в переменную типа *int*).

```
int 
fact (int n) {
  if (n < 0)
    return n;

  int r = 1, i;

  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    int p = r;
    r *= i;
    if (r / i != p) // check overflow
      return 0;
  }

  return r;
}
```

В случае ошибок возвращаем заведомо неверный результат: при переполнении ноль, а для отрицательного аргумента  число меньше нуля (сам неверный аргумент).

Answer (score 0):

РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ БЕЗ РЕКУРСИИ:

```
private static int factorial(int i) {
            int res = 1;
            int count = 1;
            while (count <= i) {
                res = res * count;
                count++;
            }
            return res;
        }
```

РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ С РЕКУРСИЕЙ:

```
private static int factorialRecurses(int num) {
        return (num == 0) ? 1 : num * (factorialRecurses(num - 1));
    }
```

Если присмотреться, то заметно повторение кода в обоих реализациях:
`num * (factorialRecurses(num - 1));` соответствует

```
res = res * count;
```

Функция вызывает функцию внутри себя до тех пор, пока не доходит до нуля. Если посмотреть в дебаггере, становится понятно, что стек вызовов функции в этот момент заполняется. Здесь достаточно вспомнить организацию стека. Функция А --> вызывает Функцию B --> вызывает Функцию C --> вызывает Функцию D и т.д., только в случае рекурсии получается, что одна и та же функция вызывает себя многократно. После чего, дойдя до крайней точки - нуля, стек  постепенно уменьшается т.к. возвращает результаты вызовов функции до момента его полного "разрушения".