# Треугольные числа. Рекурсия. Работа return в java

Tags: java

Пожалуйста поясните работу кода на примере n равного 5:

```
int triangle(int n) {
    if(n==1)          \\почему он здесь запоминает 1?, явного присваивания нет же!
        return 1;
    else
        return( n + triangle(n-1) );
}
```

Comment: Хз. Как по мне, так дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120510/ Связываю. На усмотрение других участников.

Comment: Кто запоминает `1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никто здесь ничего не запоминает.

Просто метод будет вызываться **до тех пор**, пока **параметр метода** не будет равен `1`.

Смотри пример при `n = 5;`:

```
1. triangle(5) -> n==1 ? Нет - Возвращаю [5 + Вызываю triangle(5-1(4))] 
2. triangle(4) -> n==1 ? Нет - Возвращаю [4 + Вызываю triangle(4-1(3))]
3. triangle(3) -> n==1 ? Нет - Возвращаю [3 + Вызываю triangle(3-1(2))]
4. triangle(2) -> n==1 ? Нет - Возвращаю [2 + Вызываю triangle(2-1(1))]
5. triangle(1) -> n==1 ? Да - Возвращаю [1] Рекурсия прекращена
```

А теперь, когда значение вызова метода получено, поднимаемся по действиям снизу вверх, дабы получить конечный результат.

5.`triangle(1)` Возвращено значение **[1]**;

4.`triangle(2)` Возвращаю [2 + **(triangle(1) = 1)**] = **3**

3.`triangle(3)` Возвращаю [3 + **(triangle(2) = 3)**] = **6**

2.`triangle(4)` Возвращаю [4 + **(triangle(3) = 6)**] = **10**

1.`triangle(5)` Возвращаю [5 + **(triangle(4) = 10)**] = **15**

```
Результат: 15.
```

Answer (score 2):

Когда метод вызывает сам себя, новым локальным переменным и параметрам выделяется место в стеке и код метода выполняется с этими **новыми начальными** значениями.

При каждом возврате из рекурсивного вызова старые локальные переменные и параметры удаляются из стека, и выполнение **продолжается с момента вызова внутри метода**.

`if` - чтоб выйти из рекурсии.

Если сильно утрировать, то, допустим, надо посчитать значение со входным параметром `3`.

Чтоб легче понять, представьте, что на лету автоматически создаются всё новые и новые функции, с разными именами, но с одинаковым типом принимаемого значения и возвращаемого (тобишь одинаковая сигнатура).

- итак идет функция `int triangle(int n)`,

  n равен 1? нет! Тогда надо вернуть `n + triangle(n-1)`? Да! Но там новый вызов, а нам нужно что-то вернуть.. Тогда скопируем эту функцию с другим именем и вызовем её. А тут пока постоим подождем.
- появляется функция `int triangle2(int n)`

  n равен 1? нет! Тогда надо вернуть `n + triangle2(n-1)`? Да! Опять надо кого-то ждать. Включаем тормоз. Ждем. А вызов даем следующей новой функции.
- на сцену вбегает `int triangle3(int n)`

  n равен 1? Да! Урааа! Тогда я её (единицу) возвращаю и отчаливаю отсюда. Покеда!
- единица прилетает в `triangle2` и складывается с `n` которая определена именно для этого метода, то есть `2`. 1 + 2 = 3. Эта функция тоже отчаливает на Мальдивы отдыхать. Тройка возвращается в первый метод.
- отдохнувшая самая первая функция `triangle` принимает итог выполнения `triangle2` и складывает её уже с `n`, которая принадлежит ей, то есть 3. Три плюс три = 6.
- дальше ничего выполнять не надо и делать не надо - возвращаем результат во внешний мир

---

Еще более наглядно. Грубо говоря в итоге получается так:

```
int triangle(int n) {
    return n + triangle2(2); // 3 + ?  .... ожидаем получения результата от другой функции
}

int triangle2(int n) {
    return n + triangle3(1);  // 2 + ? .... ожидаем получения результата от другой функции
}

int triangle3(int n) {
    return 1; // ничего не надо делать, т.к. n == 1 - на тебе единицу обратно
}


triangle(3);
```

---

Поэтому, по сути, никто ничего не запоминает. Один метод ждет выполнения другого метода, но с другим параметром.

Comment: а компилятор может до `n*(n+1)/2` сократить? Или он не делает таких агрессивных оптимизаций?

Comment: @pavel это надо смотреть. Скорее всего при маленьких входных данных, как выше, когда есть три вызова подряд - нечего будет оптимизировать. Ну три вызова и три вызова. А вот если 1000, к примеру, то, скорее всего что-то и с оптимизируется, т.к. будет достаточно информации анализа о коде.

Comment: @pavel: Для этого компилятору придётся очччень хорошо знать математику. Компиляция и так штука небыстрая, а перебирать все возможности для свёртки замедлит процесс ещё в несколько раз. Так что на текущих вычислительных мощностях — вряд ли.